# Allowing HTTPS connections to my Tomcat application on EC2 via a domain

Tags: ssl, tomcat, https

I'm running a Tomcat application on Amazon EC2 and I have a domain to point to the IP address. I can connect via HTTP to the IP fine but I want to connect via HTTPS.

Firstly I self-signed a certificate and my `server.xml` looked something like this:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443"
           maxParameterCount="1000"
           />

<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxParameterCount="1000"
           >
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="path/to/cert"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

I was able to connect via HTTPS but I predictably got a `MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT` error.

I then checked my domain name provider and saw they offered SSL (via PositiveSSL, if it matters). I bought one and I've set up a CNAME record like the documentation suggested:

[image: CNAME setup]

What do I do next? I still can't connect via HTTPS. Do I somehow get the certificate in a valid keystore form and pass it in to the `Connector` tag? Does my domain handle connections via HTTPS and it just interfaces with my Tomcat application on HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

I was on the right track. What should have happened when I set up the CNAME record was I would be given a link to download my certificate. The problem was that in the host of my CNAME I appended by domain, i.e. `_272731238792139323.example.com` when it should have just been `_272731238792139323` as the domain is auto-appended.

When I corrected this my certificate was automatically verified and I was emailed my `.crt` and `.ca-bundle` files. I copied them onto my server and tried to copy them to my keystore but I realised I had generated my CSR file first when I was supposed to generate a JKS file and *then* generate a CSR from that which I would provide to the certificate issuer.

So I did that and re-issued my certificate, set up the CNAME again and was provided a new certificate to download. I copied that to my server and I had to convert my `.crt` and `.ca-bundle` files to `.p7b` so they could be imported to my keystore, which I did like so:

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile your_file.crt -out your_file.p7b -certfile your_file.ca-bundle
```

I then ran:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias tomcat -file your_file.p7b -keystore yourkeystore.jks
```

and finally I updated the `server.xml` file in my tomcat/conf directory, editing the SSL connector to look like this:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxParameterCount="1000"
           >
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/certs/yourkeystore.jks"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

I restarted Tomcat and I was able to reach my domain via HTTPS.

[Further reading](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9441/33/installing-an-ssl-certificate-on-tomcat/).